# SQLServer Slow performance with Higher RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Sqlserver express 2008 (64bit) on Windows Server 2012R2 with 56GB RAM.

I have a webapplication written in c# asp.net MVC5 hosted on IIS 8.5 64bit.
This application has been hosted as a 32 bit application as it has other 32 bit dependencies.

The data retrieval happens to be extremely slow, i.e. it takes approx 1.2 mins to run a simple query which returns 5 records. I have configured sql server min server memory to 8GB and max to 28 GB (if that matters, since its express edition I dont think it does matter)

The resource monitor shows the following statistics :

- 6,82,000 Virtual Memory
- 4,27,000 Working Virtual Memory
- 1467000 sharable memory
- 82000 Private memory

The problem is that the exact same setup works perfectly fine on same config with 8GB RAM.

---

I have 2 questions :

1. Could this be a SQLserver bottleneck? If yes then how to go ahead with the troubleshooting.
2. Does 32 bit application connecting to a 64bit instance of sqlserver have performance issues? Should I try a 32 bit instance instead.

Comment: In cases like these, it would be helpful that you include: the query that is running slow, table definition(s) of tables involved, any indices created on the table(s), the execution plan of the query. It could also be that your statistics are out of date (look online for how the rebuild those), or that your indices are fragmented too much (look online on how to rebuild those).

Answer (score 1):

This is where every SQL DBA lives is when a user says my application / query is running slow.  Memory is most likely not your issue.  Often it will be a parameter sniffing issue on the query, poor indexing on the table or some other issue.  There are many ways of troubleshooting this and there are many scripts to run to find out what is going on.  I would recommend Brent Ozar's toolkit available from GITHUB and use SP_BlitzFirst, SP_BlitzIndex and sp_BlitzCache.

[Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit)